# How to effectively extract data from my process with socket io with FastAPI and React

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, socket.io, fastapi

I would like to extract newly generated height data live from the following class function as its processed and send the results over a Socket io connection to the client.

```
async def detect_and_track_single_frame(self, loop, frame):
        results = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.detection_model.predict, frame)
        boxes = results[0].boxes.data.detach().cpu().numpy()
        detections = pd.DataFrame(boxes).astype("float")

        detected_cars = [row[:4].astype(int).tolist() for index, row in detections.iterrows() if self.class_list[int(row[5])] == 'car']
        bbox_id = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.tracker.update, detected_cars)

        for bbox in bbox_id:
            x3, y3, x4, y4, id = bbox
            cx = int((x3 + x4) / 2)
            if self.center_line_x - self.offset < cx < self.center_line_x + self.offset and id not in self.vehicle_process:
                self.vehicle_process[id] = 'crossed'
                seg_img = frame[y3:y4, x3:x4]
                if seg_img.size != 0:
                    frame_path = os.path.join(self.detected_frames_dir, f'vehicle_{id}_measurement_frame.jpg')
                    cv2.imwrite(frame_path, seg_img)
                    seg_img = cv2.resize(seg_img, None, fx=0.7, fy=0.7)
                    _, _, seg_contours, _ = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.segmentation_model.detect, seg_img)
                    for seg in seg_contours:
                        y_coords = seg[:, 1]
                        min_y = np.min(y_coords)
                        max_y = np.max(y_coords)
                        vertical_extent = int(max_y - min_y)
                        logging.info(f"Vehicle ID {id}: Height measured as {vertical_extent} units.")
                        new_height = {'height': vertical_extent}
                        yield new_height
                        new_vehicle_height = VehicleDetail(vehicle_id=str(id),          height=vertical_extent)
                        logging.info(f"New VehicleDetail instance created: Vehicle ID {id},   Height {vertical_extent} units.")
                        await self.emit_vehicle_height(id, vertical_extent)
                        self.db_session.add(new_vehicle_height)
                        self.db_session.commit()
                        logging.info(f"New VehicleDetail instance created and committed:               
                        Vehicle ID {id}, Height {vertical_extent} units.")
```

The following shows the socket io server setup to collate the data and send to the client

```
import socketio
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Initialize Socket.IO server
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins='*')

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ, auth):
    logger.info(f"Client connected: {sid}")

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    logger.info(f"Client disconnected: {sid}")

@sio.event
async def vehicle_height(sid, data):
    try:
        vehicle_id = data.get('id')
        height = data.get('height')
        logger.info(f"Received height data - Vehicle ID: {vehicle_id}, Height: {height}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing height data: {e}")

def create_socketio_app(app):
    socketio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, other_asgi_app=app, socketio_path='/socket.io')
    return socketio_app
```

I have HTTP server running concurrently for the other services

```
import logging.config
from fastapi import FastAPI 
from app.database.database import get_db
from api.v1.api import api_router  
from app.core.cors import setup_cors
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from socketio_config import sio, create_socketio_app


def create_application() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(api_router, prefix="/api/v1")
    setup_cors(app)
    UPLOAD_DIR = "annotated_results"
    app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=UPLOAD_DIR), name="static")

    return app

app = create_application()
combined_app = create_socketio_app(app)

@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {"message": "Welcome to the home page!"}



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(combined_app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

I cannot find an effective way to actually send the data to the client. The logs show the server and client are connected, the height measurements are successfully stored in the Postgres DB butt he heights reading are not sent across the socket. Where could I be wrong in this setup.

Websockets have been chosen as the best method to share point to point server dada live as they are produced but I still do not get any output from the socket server.